# Unable to use SQL CASE statement in Grafana when plotting a time series?

Tags: sql, case, grafana

Trying to use a SQL query in Grafana v8.3.3 to plot a time-series to alert if no orders recieved in a previous hour, but only during essentially business hours (i.e 8am - 10pm).

Since the alert can only be run hourly, I'm going to hack the SQL query to return 1 during non-business hours (i.e 11pm - 7am) so alert will not fire.

Tried using CASE but doesn't seem to see the value returned as being a number - any thoughts on how best to fix this, or implement the above in Grafana?

Thanks in advance!

**Without CASE:**
[image: Without CASE]

```
SELECT $__timeGroup(DATE_CREATED, '1h', 0), 
1 AS "BOOKED" 
FROM CHANNEL_ORDER
WHERE STATUS = 'BOOKED'
GROUP BY $__timeGroup(DATE_CREATED, '1h', 0)
ORDER BY $__timeGroup(DATE_CREATED, '1h', 0)
```

**With CASE**
[image: With CASE]

```
SELECT $__timeGroup(DATE_CREATED, '1h', 0), 
CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(DATE_CREATED,'HH24') >= 8 AND to_char(DATE_CREATED,'HH24') <= 22) THEN COUNT(1) ELSE 1 END) AS "BOOKED" 
FROM CHANNEL_ORDER
WHERE STATUS = 'BOOKED'
GROUP BY $__timeGroup(DATE_CREATED, '1h', 0)
ORDER BY $__timeGroup(DATE_CREATED, '1h', 0)
```

Comment: Have you tried running the query your self?  Does it return what you expect?  If it does, then I would suggest putting your query into a View and then querying that view.  Also I note that your original query was returning a number in that column, but your new query is returning a string and the error seems to be complaining about not finding a number.

Answer (score 1):

Your case ***expression*** has two problems. First, you pass `DATE_CREATED` in as a parameter, but it's not in the `GROUP BY`, only `$__timeGroup(DATE_CREATED, '1h', 0)` is.

- ***All*** references in the `SELECT` ***must*** either be in the `GROUP BY` or inside an aggregate function.

Second you convert the date to a string, and compare it to an integer; this comparison is not possible and so the SQL engine ***implicitly*** converts one of the two, based on datatype order of precedence, to make them the same datatypeq. In your case, the integer is converted to a string.

As the `$__timegroup()` macro return the time rounded as an integer number of seconds, I would instead suggest something like...

```
SELECT
  $__timeGroup(DATE_CREATED, '1h', 0), 
  CASE
    WHEN $__timeGroup(DATE_CREATED, '1h', 0) % 86400 <  8*60*60 THEN 1
    WHEN $__timeGroup(DATE_CREATED, '1h', 0) % 86400 > 22*60*60 THEN 1
    ELSE COUNT(*)
  END AS "BOOKED" 
FROM CHANNEL_ORDER
WHERE STATUS = 'BOOKED'
GROUP BY $__timeGroup(DATE_CREATED, '1h', 0)
ORDER BY $__timeGroup(DATE_CREATED, '1h', 0)
```

Note: I used `%` for modulo, as I'm ***inferring*** the your underlying database is PostgreSQL?

Also, bear in mind that your use of `, 0` in the macro call means that any *hours without any data* will be assigned a result of `0`, not `1`. An alternative to a CASE expression could be...

```
SELECT
  $__timeGroup(DATE_CREATED, '1h', 1), 
  COUNT(*) AS "BOOKED" 
FROM CHANNEL_ORDER
WHERE STATUS = 'BOOKED'
  AND $__timeGroup(DATE_CREATED, '1h', 1) % 86400 >=  8*60*60
  AND $__timeGroup(DATE_CREATED, '1h', 1) % 86400 <= 22*60*60
GROUP BY $__timeGroup(DATE_CREATED, '1h', 1)
ORDER BY $__timeGroup(DATE_CREATED, '1h', 1)
```